# Shooting method in fortran (neutron star oscillation)

Tags: fortran

I have been writing a script in fortran 90 for solving the radial oscillation problem of a neutron star with the use of shooting method. But for unknown reason, my program never works out. Without the shooting method component, the program runs smoothly as it successfully constructed the star. But once the shooting comes in, everything dies.

```
   PROGRAM ROSCILLATION2
USE eos_parameters
IMPLICIT NONE
INTEGER ::i, j, k, l
INTEGER, PARAMETER :: N_ode = 5
REAL, DIMENSION(N_ode) :: y
REAL(8) :: rho0_cgs, rho0, P0, r0, phi0, pi
REAL(8) :: r, rend, mass, P, phi, delta, xi, eta
REAL(8) :: step, omega, omegastep, tiny, rho_print, Radius, B, a2, s0, lamda, E0, E
EXTERNAL :: fcn

!!!! User input 

rho0_cgs = 2.D+15           !central density in cgs unit
step = 1.D-4                ! step size dr
omegastep = 1.D-2           ! step size d(omega)
tiny = 1.D-8                ! small number P(R)/P(0) to define star surface
!!!!!!!!!
open(unit=15, file="data.dat", status="new")
pi = ACOS(-1.D0)

a2 =((((1.6022D-13)**4)*(6.674D-11)*((2.997D8)**-7)*((1.0546D-34)**-3)*(1.D6))**(0.5D0))*a2_MeV !convert to code unit (km^-1)

B = ((1.6022D-13)**4)*(6.674D-11)*((2.997D8)**-7)*((1.0546D-34)**-3)*(1.D6)*B_MeV !convert to code unit (km^-2)

s0 = (1.D0/3.D0) - (1/(6*pi**2))*a2*((1/(16*pi**2)*a2**2 + (pi**-2)*a4*(rho0 - B))**-0.5) !square of the spped of sound at r=0

lamda = -0.5D0*log(1-2*y(1)/r)

E0 = (r0**-2)*s0*exp(lamda + 3*phi0)



rho0 = rho0_cgs*6.67D-18 / 9.D0  !convert rho0 to code unit (km^-2)

!! Calculate central pressure  P0

P0 = (1.D0/3.D0)*rho0 - (4.D0/3.D0)*B - (1.D0/(a4*(12.D0)*(pi**2)))*a2**2 - &
&(a2/((3.D0)*a4))*(((1.D0/(16.D0*pi**4))*a2**2+(1.D0/(pi**2))*a4*(rho0-B))**0.5D0)


!! initial value for metric function phi 
phi0 = 0.1D0     ! arbitrary (needed to be adjusted later)
r0 = 1.D-30      ! integration starting point

!! Set initial conditions
!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
!!Start integration loop
!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
r = r0
y(1) = 0.D0
y(2) = P0
y(3) = phi0
y(4) = 1/(3*E0)
y(5) = 1
omega = 2*pi*1000/(2.997D5) !omega of 1kHz in code unit 
DO l = 1, 1000
    omega = omega + omegastep !shooting method part
DO i = 1, 1000000000

   rend = r0 + REAL(i)*step
   call oderk(r,rend,y,N_ode,fcn)

   r = rend
   mass = y(1)
   P = y(2)
   phi = y(3)
   xi = y(4)
   eta = y(5)

   IF (P < tiny*P0) THEN
      WRITE(*,*) "Central density (10^14 cgs) = ",  rho0_cgs/1.D14
      WRITE(*,*) " Mass (solar mass) = ", mass/1.477D0
      WRITE(*,*) " Radius (km) = ", r
      WRITE(*,*) " Compactness M/R ", mass/r
      WRITE(15,*) (omega*2.997D5/(2*pi)), y(5)

      GOTO 21
   ENDIF

ENDDO
ENDDO
21 CONTINUE

END PROGRAM roscillation2

!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!

SUBROUTINE fcn(r,y,yprime)
USE eos_parameters
IMPLICIT NONE 
REAL(8), DIMENSION(5) :: y, yprime
REAL(8) :: r, m, P, phi, rho, pi, B, a2, xi, eta, W, Q, E, s, lamda, omega
INTEGER :: j 

pi = ACOS(-1.D0)
a2 =((((1.6022D-13)**4)*(6.674D-11)*((2.997D8)**-7)*((1.0546D-34)**-3)*(1.D6))**(0.5D0))*a2_MeV !convert to code unit (km^-1)
B = ((1.6022D-13)**4)*(6.674D-11)*((2.997D8)**-7)*((1.0546D-34)**-3)*(1.D6)*B_MeV !convert to code unit (km^-2)
m = y(1)
P = y(2)
phi = y(3)
xi = y(4)
eta = y(5)

rho = 3.D0*P + 4.D0*B +((3.D0)/(4.D0*a4*(pi**2)))*a2**2+(a2/a4)*&
&(((9.D0/((16.D0)*(pi**4)))*a2**2+((3.D0/(pi**2))*a4*(P+B)))**0.5D0)

s = (1.D0/3.D0) - (1/(6*pi**2))*a2*((1/(16*pi**2)*a2**2 + (pi**-2)*a4*(rho - B))**-0.5) !square of speed of sound

W = (r**-2)*(rho + P)*exp(3*lamda + phi)

E = (r**-2)*s*exp(lamda + 3*phi)

Q = (r**-2)*exp(lamda + 3*phi)*(rho + P)*((yprime(3)**2) + 4*(r**-1)*yprime(3)- 8*pi*P*exp(2*lamda))

yprime(1) = 4.D0*pi*rho*r**2

yprime(2) = - (rho + P)*(m + 4.D0*pi*P*r**3)/(r*(r-2.D0*m))

yprime(3) = (m + 4.D0*pi*P*r**3)/(r*(r-2.D0*m)) 

yprime(4) = y(5)/(3*E)

yprime(5) = -(W*omega**2 + Q)*y(4)

END SUBROUTINE fcn

!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!! 
!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
!!
!! Runge-Kutta method (from Numerical Recipes)
!!
!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!

subroutine oderk(ri,re,y,n,derivs) 
INTEGER, PARAMETER :: NMAX=16
REAL(8) :: ri, re, step
REAL(8), DIMENSION(NMAX) :: y, dydx, yout
EXTERNAL :: derivs,rk4 

call derivs(ri,y,dydx) 
step=re-ri 
CALL rk4(y,dydx,n,ri,step,yout,derivs) 
do i=1,n 
   y(i)=yout(i) 
enddo
return 
end subroutine oderk

SUBROUTINE RK4(Y,DYDX,N,X,H,YOUT,DERIVS) 
INTEGER, PARAMETER :: NMAX=16 
REAL(8) :: H,HH,XH,X,H6 
REAL(8), DIMENSION(N) :: Y, DYDX, YOUT 
REAL(8), DIMENSION(NMAX) :: YT, DYT, DYM 
EXTERNAL :: derivs


HH=H*0.5D0 
H6=H/6D0 
XH=X+HH

DO I=1,N 
   YT(I)=Y(I)+HH*DYDX(I) 
ENDDO

CALL DERIVS(XH,YT,DYT) 

DO I=1,N 
   YT(I)=Y(I)+HH*DYT(I) 
ENDDO

CALL DERIVS(XH,YT,DYM) 

DO I=1,N 
   YT(I)=Y(I)+H*DYM(I) 
   DYM(I)=DYT(I)+DYM(I) 
ENDDO

CALL DERIVS(X+H,YT,DYT) 

DO I=1,N 
   YOUT(I)=Y(I)+H6*(DYDX(I)+DYT(I)+2*DYM(I)) 
ENDDO


END SUBROUTINE RK4
```

Any reply would be great i am just really depressed for the long debugging.

Comment: What is the problem?  In the code you've posted you assign `omega`, increment it and print it but use it nowhere else.  What is it that isn't working?  How does actual behavior differ from expected behavior?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your program is blowing up because of this line:

```
yprime(5) = -(W*omega**2 + Q)*y(4)
```

in subroutine `fcn`.  In this subroutine, `omega` is completely independent of the one declared in your main program.  This one is uninitialized and used in an expression, which will either contain random values or zero, if your compiler is nice enough (or told) to initialize variables.

If you want the variable `omega` from your main program to be the same variable you use in `fcn` then you need to pass that variable to `fcn` somehow.  Due to the way you've architected this program, passing it would require modifying all of your procedures to pass `omega` so that it can be provided to all of your calls to `DERIVS` (which is the dummy argument you are associating with `fcn`).

An alternative would be to put `omega` into a module and `use` that module where you need access to `omega`, e.g. declare it in `eos_parameters` instead of declaring it in the scoping units of `fcn` and your main program.

Comment: good call.  ( technically `omega` could be in module `eos_parameters` .. ) Setting your compiler to flag uninitialized variables would be a good idea.

Comment: @agentp good catch that he was already using a module in that way.  I've edited accordingly.