# Solving Rossler Attractor using Runge-Kutta 4

Tags: algorithm, fortran, runge-kutta

I am trying to get a solution for the Rossler attractor system using RK-4, with parameters a=0.2, b=0.2, c=6 and initial conditions x0=-5.6, y0=0, z0=0. I tried solving using Fortran but the result is only displaying the initial conditions even after 1000 iterations. What mistakes am I making?

```
implicit none
external rossler
integer::i,j=0,n,nstep
real::a,b,c,y1(3),t0,dt,t1,t2,ya(3),yb(3),yd(3),t,x0,y0,z0,x(1000),y(1000),z(1000),k1(3),k2(3),k3(3),k4(3),h
print *, "enter the values of a,b,c"
read (*,*) a,b,c
print *, "enter the values of x0,y0,z0"
read (*,*) x0,y0,z0
n=3
t0=0.0
h=0.05
ya(1)=x0
ya(2)=y0
ya(3)=z0
nstep=1000
do i=1,nstep
t1=t0
t2=t0+h
call rk4(rossler,t1,t2,1,N,k1,k2,k3,k4,Ya,Y1,Yb)

x(i)=ya(1)
y(i)=ya(2)
z(i)=ya(3)
open (99,file="rossler.txt")
write(99,*) x(i),y(i),z(i)
end do

end program

subroutine rossler(T,Yd,YB,N)
implicit none
integer n
real t,yb(n),yd(n),a,b,c
yd(1)=-yb(2)-yb(3)
Yd(2)=yb(1)+a*yb(2)
Yd(3)=b+yb(3)*(yb(1)-c)
return
end

subroutine rk4(rossler,t1,t2,nstep,N,k1,k2,k3,k4,Ya,Y1,Yb)
implicit none
external rossler
integer nstep,n,i,j
REAL T1,T2,Ya(N),k1(n),k2(n),k3(n),k4(n),H,Y1(N),T,yb(n)
T=T1+(I-1)*H
CALL rossler(T,Yb,Ya,N)
DO J=1,N
k1(j)=YB(J)*H
end do
CONTINUE
CALL rossler(T+0.5*H,Yb,Ya+k1*0.5,N)
DO J=1,N
k2(j)=YB(J)*H
enddo
CONTINUE
CALL rossler(T+0.5*H,Yb,Ya+k2*0.5,N)
DO J=1,N
K3(J)=YB(J)*H
enddo
CONTINUE
CALL rossler(T+H,Yb,Ya+k3,N)
DO J=1,n
K4(J)=YB(J)*H
Y1(J)=Ya(J)+(k1(j)+k4(j)+2.0*(k2(j)+k3(j)))/6.0
enddo
CONTINUE
DO J=1,N
Ya(J)=Y1(j)
enddo
CONTINUE
enddo
RETURN
END
```

Comment: The first mistake you're making is not spending enough money on indentation to make the structure of the code clear, either to yourself or to random strangers such as myself.  Second mistake might be related to the parameter `T` in the argument list of `rossler`; it's not used by the subroutine at all.  Check that.  Then get rid of the useless `continue` statements -- as far as I can tell that means all of them.  While Fortran is insensitive to the case you use in names (ie `Yb` *is* the same variable as `yb`) we humans find inattention to such details distracting.

Comment: And in addition to those comments above (although I don't know about `t` because I've no idea on the equations so I'm not going to check), I'd suggest using explicit interfaces for the subroutines: a compiler will do checks against your calls much more happily than I will.

Comment: not having touched fortran in three decades, I'm dubious about `real […,] a,b,c` in `subroutine rossler()` - doesn't that _declare_ local variables `a, b, c`, leaving them initialised at 0.0, possibly hiding the ones read?

Comment: @greybeard That's surely the answer - except for the point that there's no initialization (to 0.0 or anything else), and that there's no hiding of anything.  The other variables called `a` etc., aren't in anything like the same scope.

Comment: @greybeard If i dont include declaration for a,b,c in the subroutine (rossler), then an error message is displayed, asking their implicit type to be specified. How do I go around this?

Comment: @High Performance Mark I beg your pardon. I am new to this area. I'll take your suggestions and modify the program.

Comment: While I might tend to pass any parameters explicitly (if in/as an array/derived type), roygvib seems to have done a much better job at changing your code minimally invasive than I could hope for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Although the question seems a duplicate of [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32482288/shooting-method-in-fortran-neutron-star-oscillation), here I am attaching a minimally modified code so that the OP can compare it with the original one. The essential modifications are that I have removed all the unused variables, moved `a`, `b`, `c`, and `h` to a parameter module, and cleaned up unnecessary statements (like `CONTINUE`). No newer features of Fortran introduced (including `interface` block for `rossler`), so it is hopefully straight-forward to see how the code has been changed.

```
module params
    real :: a, b, c, h
end module

program main
    use params, only: a, b, c, h
    implicit none
    external rossler
    integer :: i, n, nstep
    real :: t, y(3)

    a = 0.2
    b = 0.2
    c = 5.7
    n = 3
    t = 0.0
    h = 0.05
    y(1) = -5.6
    y(2) = 0.0
    y(3) = 0.0
    nstep = 7000

    open(99, file="rossler.txt")
    do i = 1,nstep
        call rk4 ( rossler, t, n, y )
        write(99,*) y(1), y(2), y(3)
    end do

end program

subroutine rossler ( t, dy, y, n )
    use params, only: a, b, c
    implicit none
    integer n
    real t, dy(n), y(n)
    dy(1) = -y(2) - y(3)
    dy(2) = y(1) + a * y(2)
    dy(3) = b + ( y(1) - c ) * y(3)
end

subroutine rk4 ( deriv, t, n, y )
    use params, only: h
    implicit none
    external deriv
    integer n, j
    real y(n), t, k1(n), k2(n), k3(n), k4(n), d(n)

    call deriv ( t, d, y, n )
    do j = 1,n
        k1(j) = d(j) * h
    enddo

    call deriv ( t+0.5*h, d, y+k1*0.5, n )
    DO j = 1,n
        k2(j) = d(j) * h
    enddo

    call deriv ( t+0.5*h, d, y+k2*0.5, n )
    do j = 1,n
        k3(j) = d(j) * h
    enddo

    call deriv ( t+h, d, y+k3, n )
    do j = 1,n
        k4(j) = d(j) * h
        y(j) = y(j) + ( k1(j) + k4(j) + 2.0 * (k2(j) + k3(j)) ) / 6.0
    enddo

    t = t + h
end
```

By choosing the parameters as `a = 0.2, b = 0.2, c = 5.7` and `nstep = 7000`, the modified code gave the so-called [Rössler attractor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/R%C3%B6ssler_attractor), which is very beautiful and appears close in pattern to that displayed in the Wiki page. So with the minimal modifications, I believe the OP will also get a similar picture (it may be interesting to see how the pattern changes depending on parameters).

2D projection of the trajectory onto the xy plane:
[image: Projection onto the xy plane]

Comment: Is there a reason that in `rk4` you use vectorized operations in the function calls of `deriv` but loops in between? Could they not also be expressed as `k1 = h*d` etc.?

Comment: @LutzL You are absolutely right, but I intentionally left the explicit loops so that it makes easier for the OP to make a comparison (e.g., no "CONTINUE" statements are necessary). But yes, I hope the OP will rewrite them to a vectorized form also.

Comment: Hi, I have never aware of `deriv`. Is it in standard? (I checked it works with gfortran and ifort), but cant see where it is defined

Comment: Hi @BaRud This `deriv` is a dummy argument of the subroutine `rk4`, so its name is actually arbitrary. It will be bound (or connected) to the corresponding actual argument of `call rk4 ( rossler, t, n, y )`,  so that `deriv` becomes equal to `rossler` inside the `rk4` routine. There is no subroutine named `deriv` (in other files or in the standard).

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is exactly the same as in [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32482288), although I can no longer vote to close as a duplicate.

To make explicit and add the comments on the question: `a`, `b` and `c` take the place of `omega` from that question; the subroutine `rossler` as the function `fcn`.

An answer to that question addresses how this issue can be resolved.